# By adding a new column add celldata at index of the column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a `datatable-manager` by using `javascript` and `jquery`. When I add a new column to the table, I want to fill all cells on all rows at the index of the column with a "defaulttext".

[image: example Picture]

As you can see on the picture the cells at the index of the new column should get a text.

As a beginner, I'm struggling with the code. I hope someone gets what I want to reach and can help :)

```js
function AddColumnToDataTable(){

      $('#tableHeader').append("<td>" + GetEmptyText() + "</td>"); 
      // Add a new Column Header to the Table

      var columnIndex =  $('#dataTable').rows[2].cells.length; 
      // The columnIndex of the new column (the headers start on row 3)

      var rowCount = (-3) + $('#dataTable').getElementsByTagName("tr").length; 
      // Count the rows except the first 3 rows / only the data rows not the title, header and button rows

      var textToAppend = "<td>" + GetEmptyText() + "</td>"; 
      // the default text to fill

      var rows = $('tr', '#dataTable'); 
      // get the rows in the table

    for (var i = 3; i <= rowCount; i++) {
      rows.eq(i).html(textToAppend);         
      // loop through all rows starting on row 3 and add the text
    // the column index is missing
    }
}
```

Comment: you could something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mvsxbysn/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When i have the cellindex, how can i use this after already appending the text 3 lines above? Maybe i don't understand your code well enough :/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/maverickosama92/mvsxbysn/1/ how about this.

Comment: is it ok to have a function in a loop =?

Comment: yes you can have. Did it solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i got it by using

```
function AddColumnToDataTable(){
  $('#tableHeader').append("<th> Header </th>");
  $('table th').last().attr("contenteditable", true).focus();
  $('#tableBody').find("tr").each(function() {
          $(this).append("<td> Content </td>");
      });
}
```